# Excel: Lookup Cell then Compare Numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Trying to lookup a certain row in a table and then compare two numbers within that row. Essentially perform a lookup formula and *then* perform an `IF` statement.

To elaborate, I am an officer in a college club that run various tabletop games in different rooms. I am trying to keep an organized list of games that are occurring. I have a list of all of the games that are happening (first picture), but I am trying to separate the games based on week. I am trying to determine automatically whether or not a certain game as availability, and to list either true or false in a separate table on a separate sheet (second picture).

I currently have all of the information sorted by using the `FILTER` function, if there is a better way to keep the information organized that may solve this issue better than what I'm trying to do, I'm all ears.

Also, please excuse missing data. I haven't gotten around to working on date formatting yet.

This is the master list of all of the games:
[image: Games Master List]

And this is the filtered list for A week games:
[image: A Week Games]

Comment: Can you provide us with the formula you have tried?

Comment: Not really getting you - `=XLOOKUP("Test A",$A$2:$A$13,$F$2:$F$13)` would return the value in column F, `=XLOOKUP("Test A",$A$2:$A$13,$G$2:$G$13)` would return the value in column G for Test A.  So `=IF(XLOOKUP("Test A",$A$2:$A$13,$G$2:$G$13)<XLOOKUP("Test A",$A$2:$A$13,$F$2:$F$13),"Spaces available","Table full")` compares the two.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list and use Filter function in table:

```
=FILTER($A$2:$A$13,$D$2:$D$13=$K$1,"")
```

[image]